# How do I find out if a DOM element is a scroll container?

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

Is there a way to find out if an DOM element has scroll capabilities without checking its styles?

Currently, I'm looking for `overflow: auto` or `scroll` on the element. I'd like to know a JavaScript method that can check if the element is the scroll container for a deeply-nested child element.

**[EDIT]**

This isn't to find out if it's got a scrollbar showing; I wanna know if it's a container that would display a scrollbar if the contents extend past the container height.

In my experience, the browser is doing this naturally sometimes, but I can't figure out why. That tells me there's something on the container in JS saying "I will display scrollbars when the content is larger".

I was thinking it could have something to do with `height: 100%` and `position: absolute`, but then there are bound to be other situations as well.

Strangely, the browser is showing these elements as `overflow: visible` from the user-agent stylesheet, but it should never show scrollbars in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the clientHeight of the element com the scroll height of it.

I made a function that makes it.

```js
var myDiv = document.querySelector("#my_div_1");
var myDiv2 = document.querySelector("#my_div_2");

console.log("There's scroll in my_div 1 = " + hasScrollY(myDiv));
console.log("There's scroll in my_div 2 = " + hasScrollY(myDiv2));

function hasScrollY(elem) {
  return elem.clientHeight < elem.scrollHeight;
}
```

```css
#my_div_1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#my_div_2 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 60px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

p {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="my_div_1">
  <p>
    This is a div with overflow
  </p>
</div>
<br>
<div id="my_div_2">
  <p>
    This is a div without overflow
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: *Went ahead and updated my question to clarify.* I saw answers like this on StackOverflow, but I don't need to know if the contents are larger than the container. I actually need to know if the container would show a scrollbar or not when the contents extend past the boundaries. Typically, the browser has `overflow: visible`, but for some reason, it will add scrollbars in specific cases like `position: absolute; height: 100%`.

Comment: Yes, it's a hard question! The way browser renders the html content its not very previsible. Maybe you can show some examples, but i guess its not very easy to do.